# Can't Install Plugin Via Composer

Tags: plugins, composer

I set up a basic plugin using https://pluginfactory.io/

The package name is `kgrote`

The plugin name is `siteutilities`

Then I put it in a subfolder next to my Craft project folder:

```
/site
|-- craft
|-- craft-plugins
  |-- kgrote
    |-- siteutilities
```

Then I added this to `craft/composer.json`:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "../craft-plugins/kgrote/siteutilities"
    }
]
```

Then I ran this command in the Craft project folder:

`composer require kgrote/siteutilities`

Then I got this error:

> Could not find a matching version of package kgrote/siteutilities.
>   Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the
>   package is available in a stability which matches your
>   minimum-stability (stable).

Here is the contents of my `craft/composer.json` file:

```
{
  "require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "3.0.23.1",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0",
    "craftcms/aws-s3": "1.0.8",
    "craftcms/redactor": "2.1.6",
    "ether/seo": "3.4.3"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "../craft-plugins/kgrote/siteutilities"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the contents of my plugin `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "kgrote/site-utilities",
    "description": "Helper functions for this website.",
    "type": "craft-plugin",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "keywords": [
        "craft",
        "cms",
        "craftcms",
        "craft-plugin",
        "site utilities"
    ],
    "support": {
        "docs": "???",
        "issues": "???"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Kristen Grote"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "craftcms/cms": "^3.0.0-RC1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "kgrote\\siteutilities\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "name": "Site Utilities",
        "handle": "site-utilities",
        "hasCpSettings": false,
        "hasCpSection": false,
        "changelogUrl": "???",
        "class": "kgrote\\siteutilities\\SiteUtilities"
    }
}
```

Don't really know what I'm doing wrong here. How does composer know what `kgrote/siteutilities` is if it's not defined in the `composer.json` file? Shouldn't that be part of the `"repositories"` config setting?

Comment: You may need to paste your composer file for the plugin itself and your full project composer file to help us work out exactly what the problem is. In the past I’ve had to delete my vendors directory and composer lock file to force composer to fetch everything fresh.

Comment: @Jay Updated with `composer.json` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From looking at your plugin's `composer.json` file, I think you've got the package name wrong – instead of

```
composer require kgrote/siteutilities
```

you'll probably want

```
composer require kgrote/site-utilities
```

I.e. the plugin folder's name doesn't matter – it's the `name` entry in your plugin's `composer.json` file that determines the package name.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks! Also explains how composer knows what the package name is.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `kgrote/siteutilities` to your "require" section in your main composer file then changing your "name" in the plugin composer file to match should help.

Don't forget to update the plugin version number to try to force composer top get the latest versions. I've found it caches in the Vendors directory though. So make the above changes and delete the composer.lock file and the Vendors directory and install everything from scratch.